# Display custom message using CSS - alternate approach to Bootstrap modals

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to display a custom message box that an item was added to the cart.I have tried using Bootstrap modals but would want to use CSS instead.The message box  should slide from the header and display the message and then dissapear(similar to Bootstrap modals).

```
<div>
<button type="button" id="notifyProductName" ></button>
</div>

<script>
var display = document.getElementById("notifyProductName");
  display.innerHTML = productName + " was added to cart";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but if you are looking for simple CSS animation.

If you are I think you can use 'transition' property.

Please try this HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div id="popup-msg">
      <h4>Product Notification</h4>
      <button type="button" id="notifyProductName">OK</button>
    </div>

    <button onclick="popupMsg()">pop</button>

    <script>
    var popupMsg = function() {
        document.getElementById("popup-msg").style['opacity'] = '1';
        document.getElementById("popup-msg").style['top'] = '50px';
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
#popup-msg {
  position: absolute;
  top: -200px;
  left: calc(50% - 200px);
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: lightgray;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #AAAAAA;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.25s;
}
```

When you change 'opacity' and 'top' properties from Javascript, it takes some time defined by 'transition' property.

You can make simple animation using this.

Here is my JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wiany11/07gks6x9/